# How to use postgres COPY in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, copy, nestjs

I'm building a nestjs application that uses postgres.
I have some big data (from 100 to 10 millions entries and more) that I receive through an API.
I need to write this data to a postgres DB.

I researched a bit and found out that I should use COPY to do a bulk insert.

I tested `COPY` in console mode using `psql` and it works.
But I can't find any example how to do it through js code.

Here is what I've tried:

```
const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();
await queryRunner.startTransaction();

//throws error 'syntax error at or near "123"'
const query = `COPY ${table}(key) FROM stdin \n123\t\n321\t\n147\t\n\\.\n`;

// using INSERT works as expected
//const query = `INSERT INTO ${table}(key) VALUES ('123'), ('321'), ('147');`;
await queryRunner.query(query);


await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
await queryRunner.release();
```

The above code throws this error:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "123" at character 33`

Can anyone explain/point into direction how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Please include the errors you're getting in the question

Comment: The Postgresql COPY command works for copying data from a file to a table , or exports data from a table to a file. In above case, you are giving STDIN as source, which may work in command line console. For use inside program, use a csv file that has your records. And, for the approach you mention, you need to have batched csv files that you iterate and copy to postgres db, not all at one go.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Is there a way to pass to COPY as source an array/list or it is limited to stdin and prepared files on disc? Thanks

Comment: I do not think so. There is a parameter to execute a shell command and the output of which can be used as a source, see the syntax [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html)